# An intricate integral involving indicator functions

Tags: integration

Consider the following integral:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\text{ }\mathrm{d}\phi(x)$$
where $\phi(x)$ is defined as:
$$\phi(x)=A\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}(x_i<x)$$

Where the $x_i$'s are a sequence of known real numbers. How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\phi$ is a superposition of Heavyside functions. Their derivative are Dirac's delta functions. When integrated, these delta functions translate to evaluation of the integrand function, so the solution is related to the values of $f$ at your points $x_i$.

As a side comment, you did not define the sequence $x_i$, I assume they are a known list of real numbers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heavyside functions. Could you provide me with a concrete example? Otherwise a link could also be helpful. 
Besides, I have now corrected the question.

Comment: Sure. Strictly speaking they are distributions. The Heavyside distribution $H$ is defined as 0 if $x<0$, 1 if $x>0$ and $H(0)=1/2$. Their derivative in the sense of distributions is Dirac's delta, i.e. defined as the limit of a sequence of functions. This resulting distribution is 0 for $x\neq 0$ and $\infty$ at $x=0$, as you would expect from the graph of $H$.

Comment: In particular, Dirac's delta satisfies the following

Comment: $$\int f(x)\delta(x)dx=f(0)$$ for a class of good functions $f$, assuming the integral interval contains 0 (else, the integral is zero).

Comment: Ok. But I still can't make sense of the inequality in the Heavyside function? What does it mean to have $\delta(x_i<x)$?

Comment: Well, $1(x_i<x)=H(x-x_i)$.